# Syncing multiple Azure tables / containers in C# - whats the best practice?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure storage topology with multiple nodes which are mirrored, but can have different data depending on what user in what region is using what container node.

My requirement is to sync the 3 node tables into a master node table. For example, if the table was Users, the three nodes (Node A, Node B, Node C) would populate the main User table with the result of a union of the three nodes, ignoring duplicates and removing not longer referenced rows.

The "Big Hammer" approach (if I was doing this in SQL) would be to get the list of Users from the master table, the 3 lists of nodes, combine the nodes into a new collection, compare that collection to the master collection and perform a merge/union of the data, finally pushing that new merged and truncated collection up to that master node.

My questions are:

1. Is there a built in Azure way of doing this?
2. Would doing this in C# as I desribed above be a good practice?
3. What types of problems / risk can occur, and what considerations should be taken?
4. Can you suggest a better solution to this problem; something tried and true (a design pattern maybe?)
5. Can you provide a code sample for doing this in C#?

I assume that if azure has no mechanism to help support this feature, then azure can be taken out of the mix and this becomes a pure C# List Manipulation problem.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, but behind the scenes Microsoft does geo-replicate/locally replicate your azure tables up to 5 additional times (6 copies total)..they may release an explicit API for this
2) Depends on the size of your data/frequency of the job...remember you get charges per/transactions..if you start doing billions of rows every 4 hours, then this will start costing a lot of money
3) I would do this on a worker role, so the data does not have to leave the MS data center and this would improve the performance.  In a worker role, it could also be "scheduled" to run at specific intervals

Azure Table Storage is not really a great solution for this.  Syncing across persisted storage is provided in SQL Database between databases.  While, it is not an Azure specific problem extracting the data and processing all these operations in an atomic way is important.